# Error with Poco

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I want to use Poco libraries in my C++ project.
But I get an error on compilation.

I'm developing on Ubuntu OS, CLion 1.2.4 IDE

Here it is my source code:

```
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int arc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(rcp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

include_directories("libraries")

add_executable(rcp ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(rcp pthread PocoNet PocoUtil PocoFoundation)
```

And this is the output when I do the compilation:

```
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::host() const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImpl4hostEv[_ZNK4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImpl4hostEv]+0x11): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress(void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::~IPv6SocketAddressImpl()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplD2Ev[_ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplD5Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::~IPv6SocketAddressImpl()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplD0Ev[_ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::~IPv4SocketAddressImpl()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplD2Ev[_ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplD5Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::~IPv4SocketAddressImpl()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplD0Ev[_ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target '/home/john/projects/rightChoiceProperty/bin/rcp' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/john/projects/rightChoiceProperty/bin/rcp] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rcp.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'rcp' failed
make: *** [rcp] Error 2
```

Where is my problem I have search all of today but I couldn't find anything please help me to resolve this problem.

Thank you every body

Comment: The output suggests you didn't actually link against `Poco::Net`. Another possibility might be if you're using Poco headers from a different version of Poco than the compiled library you are linking against

Comment: @M.M Thank you for your feedback.
Maybe you are right because one I have installed Poco from source and then I have installed from apt-get install. So what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, as " M.M " guide in above comment:

> The output suggests you didn't actually link against Poco::Net.
>   Another possibility might be if you're using Poco headers from a
>   different version of Poco than the compiled library you are linking
>   against

I removed changed the include to include right library.

At first this was my include line:

```
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
```

Changed to

```
#include <Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h>
```

Everything is working fine now.

Thank you M.M

Comment: This suggests you might have two different copies of Poco headers on your system (one in the search path for `< >` and one in the path for `" "`). To avoid other such errors maybe it'd be good to locate and uninstall the incorrect header set.  It's better style to only use `< >` for system headers. so my advice would be to uninstall the wrong set of headers and then use `" "` (which would then find the correct set).